# Managed Property "Rank" not sortable

Tags: search, managed-property, 2016

Is there a documented reason why the `Rank` Managed Property is no longer sortable in SharePoint 2016?

Note, that the managed property was also not marked as sortable in SP2013 but it was somehow working there and throws an exception in 2016:
[image: Schema in SP 2013 / 2016]

What is the workaround for this?

Following exception is logged, when executing a query with a sort condition on Rank:

```
Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.InvalidPropertyException: Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationFault]: SortList    Server stack trace:     
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown
 at [0]:     
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.IImsService.Execute(QueryProperties properties, Guid ssaId)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication._ImsQueryInternalType.<>c__DisplayClassa8.<Execute>b__a6(IImsService serviceApplication)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication._ImsQueryInternalType.DoImsOp[T](ImsBackedOperation`1 imsCall, String endpointName, IImsService serviceApplication, String operationName)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication._ImsQueryInternalType.DoSpLoadBalancedImsOp[T](ImsBackedOperation`1 imsCall, QueryProperties properties, String operationName)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ExceptionUtilities.ThrowImsServiceBackwardCompatibleException(FaultException`1 ex)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication._ImsQueryInternalType.DoSpLoadBalancedImsOp[T](ImsBackedOperation`1 imsCall, QueryProperties properties, String operationName)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication._ImsQueryInternalType.DoSpImsOp[T](ImsBackedOperation`1 imsCall, QueryProperties properties, String operationName, Uri directImsUri)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication._ImsQueryInternalType.Execute(QueryProperties properties, Guid ssaId)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query query)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on server, so you can edit this Managed Property and enable Sort to true.
After this do Full Crawl and it will works.